# How to return the Entered Value from Mapping Corresponds to address[msg.sender]

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I am hitting hard to creating a lottery smart contract in solidity. I have tried a couple of ways, first I stored all the players address inside an array, but unfortunately that logic fail, just because of slow execution of array (when entries are more 1000+).

Now I am trying mapping `mapping(address => Struct) entries;`. Now what I have done here. I created a structure with user first ticket number and user last ticket number i.e `uint userFstTcktNumber;`
`uint userLstTcktNumber;`

Here is my structure

```
struct UserInfo {
        uint userFstTcktNumber;
        uint userLstTcktNumber;
    } UserInfo userinfo;
```

Then I created a mapping

```
mapping(address => UserInfo )  public entry;
```

Then I have Created a function to enter the values inside the mapping and structure.

```
   function letsdo(uint first, uint last) public{
        entry[msg.sender];
        userinfo.userLstTcktNumber = first;
        userinfo.userLstTcktNumber = last;
    }
```

Now what I want to do? I just want to get the values from the mapping and structure corresponding to the address, let's say I have 10 entries from `1 to 10` from address `"0x617F2E2fD72FD9D5503197092aC168c91465E7f2"` . And I have another 50 entries from `11 to 51` from another address `"0x14723A09ACff6D2A60DcdF7aA4AFf308FDDC160C"`.

To return this I am using the function

```
   function get(address) public view returns(uint, uint){
         return (userinfo.userFstTcktNumber, userinfo.userLstTcktNumber); 
      }
```

But it's not returning me the expected result.

It's always returning the `userFstTcktNumber` is 0, no matter what address I have passed inside the `get()`.

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really using your map, you need to set the values to be able to search inside it.

```
function letsdo(uint first, uint last) public {
    entry[msg.sender] = UserInfo(first, last);
}
```

You don't need a `get` function as well, since entry is already public, you can search directly using `entry[<address>]`

`UserInfo userinfo` after your struct is also unnecessary, since you want to work with map, you will need more than just an instance, the `letsdo` function I mentioned above is already doing it

Answer (score 1):

Hey thanks everyone for helping me out, Actually Last night I sorted it out my own. And here is the full logic for the problem.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18; 

contract lottery{
    uint public lastTicketNumber = 0;
    uint youEntredWithAmount;
    address [] public players;
    uint public entryFee =  0.01 ether;
    
    struct UserInfo {
        uint userFstTcktNumber;
        uint userLstTcktNumber;
    }
    
    mapping(address => UserInfo ) public entry;
    
    function letsdo(uint first, uint last) public{
        players.push(msg.sender);
        entry[msg.sender].userFstTcktNumber = first;
        entry[msg.sender].userLstTcktNumber = last;
    }
    
    function currentLevel(address userAddress) public constant returns (uint, uint) {
        return (entry[userAddress].userFstTcktNumber, entry[userAddress].userLstTcktNumber);
    }
    
 
      
      function numberOfParticipents() public view returns(address [] memory){
          return players;
      }
}
```